# Algorithm to calculate shortest time in which two people can collect K items from N cities

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, shortest-path

There are N cities connected via M bidirectional roads. Each road connects exactly 2 different cities and has a travel time associated with it.

There are K different items in these cities. Given the list of items at each city. Two people are standing at city number 1. They both collectively need to get all K items in minimal amount of time. To do this, they decide to split the shopping between themselves in the following way.

Both people chose their own paths, starting at city 1 and ending at city N. They don’t necessarily need to take the same paths.
While travelling, each of them will collect items at certain cities.
When both people reach city N, they must have collectively purchased all K items.
If one person finishes before the other, he waits at city N for his partner to finish. This means the total time is the max of their respective travel times. Any person can visit city N in between, but they both HAVE to finish their paths at city N.

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: So basically the traveling salesman problem, except that you have two salesmen, you need visit at most K cities instead of all cities, and you can end anywhere. Not sure what you expect to get from an SO question, other than, "Good luck with that!"

Comment: cheater in a programming competition

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if it's correct but we may proceed this way:

since total travel time is max(t_1,t_2) where t_i is travel time of cat_i,so we first travel the graph(tree) using dijkstra algorithm while noting down waht types of fishes have been collected....after cat1 is done,cat2 starts its traversal.now it will travel a given edge if the other endpoint contains type of fish that hasnt been collected.if there are more than one such candidates,then the path with low cost is selected